# Why is this example code making use of process.nextTick?

Tags: node.js, express

I came across this express.js route which is part of a [small example in its official repo](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/error/index.js), demonstrating how to handle errors, have a look:

```js
app.get('/next', function(req, res, next) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    next(new Error('oh no!'));
  });
});
```

What I understand about `process.nextTick()` is that, it makes a pieces of code to be executed asynchronously. But the confusing part is that: aren't the route handlers in express asynchronous by default? why did this code need to make use of `process.nextTick()` in the route handler given they are executed asynchronously by default? Viewing the whole code in the repo I linked above may make my question more clear, don't worry, the whole repo is 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've shown us, there is no reason to use `process.nextTick()` in that code example.

The code could have just directly called `next(new Error('oh no!'))` like this:

```
app.get('/next', function(req, res, next) {
    next(new Error('oh no!'));
});
```

`process.nextTick()` is used when you want to postpone when something runs until immediately after the rest of the event handler code runs.  But, in the example you show, there is no other code in the event handler so there is nothing else to run - therefore there is little practical reason to use the `process.nextTick()` here.

The best I can guess is that they are just showing a code example that illustrates that `next()` can be called asynchronously some time in the future if desired and it does not have to be called synchronously.  They could have just as well used `fs.readFile()` or `setTimeout()`, both of which have async callbacks and then called `next()` from within those callbacks - all to demonstrate that you just call `next()` whenever your operation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get you head around the fact that node is not truly asynchronous.  Each pass through the event loop will run to completion. Of course you arrange things (with callbacks or promises or events) so that each run to completion is very short and doesn't block anywhere, but during the run nothing else does.  This is unlike a true multi-process/multi-task operating system like linux, where a thread could get interrupted at any time.

True multitasking is hard, because whatever you do you have cater for the fact that things may get interrupted at any time, where as node makes it easier as you can be sure your current thread makes it to the end.

So if you have something either you want to ensure runs later, or - as I think this example is showing - you don't need it to run immediately and it would be better to get out of the way and let other parts of the system have their say, then you call process.nextTick().